# bad substitution with string slices in bash

Tags: bash

I'm trying to make a script that will append the port number to the host-name i extract from the computer but when i try to create slice from a string in bash it wont let me. i keep getting a bad substitution error in line 4. I have tried multiple things including using += but that just give me the same error

```
#! /bin/bash
addr=$(hostname -I)
len=${#addr}
echo "${addr:0:10}" # why does this not work? i tried it without quotes also, get same error
#echo "${addr:0:$len}" # am i a able to use variables in the slice
```

Comment: Judging from the error message, you may be running the script on `sh` not `bash`.

Comment: What is the *exact* output you desire?  When asking a question, you should include that information.  You should take the [tour] and read [ask] and [mvce].  The subsitution works for me, but I did remove the spce, like @markp-fuso suggested.

Comment: @markp-fuso Spaces are almost universally allowed after `#!` in a shebang -- in fact, Dennis Ritchie's original announcement of this feature included an example with a space. (Though apparently systemd is an exception.) See [this Unix&Linux question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/276751/is-space-allowed-between-and-bin-bash-in-shebang) and the various links in the answers.

Comment: @mariobar : You script looks fine to me and works for me. Please change, for debugging purpose, your `echo` line into: `echo version=$BASH_VERSION - address="$addr"` and tell us the output you get.